# Why is there a ClassLoader exception when there are 2 objects with similar type names

Tags: java, classloader, uniqueidentifier, identifier, local-class

I have a class with 2 methods.

- In `method1()`, I create a `local record` called `Abc`. This `local record` is only available to `method1()` because it was ***defined*** in `method1()` ([here are the rules on it according to Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3)).
- In `method2()`, I create a `local interface` called `ABC`. Notice that there is a capitalization difference here. The `local record` was named `Abc`, but this `local interface` is named `ABC`.

Here is the class.

```java
//package ..... //commenting out package information, as I sincerely doubt that is the cause

/** There seems to be a class loader error when running the below method in main(). */
public class ClassLoaderIssue
{

   /** Method 1. */
   private void method1()
   {
   
      record Abc(int a)
      {
      
         public static String iDontCare()
         {
         
            return "ignore this method";
         
         }
      
      }
      
      System.out.println(Abc.iDontCare()); //error
   
   }
   
   /** Method 2. */
   private void method2()
   {
   
      interface ABC
      {
      
      }
      
   }
   
 
   /**
    * 
    * Main method.
    * 
    * @param   args  commandline arguments that we don't care about for this example.
    * 
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      new ClassLoaderIssue().method1();
   
   }
   
}
```

And here is the Exception that I get.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ClassLoaderIssue$1ABC (wrong name: ClassLoaderIssue$1Abc)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at ClassLoaderIssue.method1(ClassLoaderIssue.java:23)
    at ClassLoaderIssue.main(ClassLoaderIssue.java:49)
```

And here is some relevant information.

```
Java compile command = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin\javac.exe
Java run command = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin\java.exe
```

Obviously, this is just a runnable example of the problem, but I have a situation where it is extremely convenient and helpful to have `local class/enum/record` to handle weird state at the very edges of my domain. Therefore, I use this pattern a lot, but this is the first time I have come across this issue.

Now obviously, there are many ways to go around this. The simplest being that I could just rename the enum for one. I already tried that and that worked. Same for the interface.

But why does this happen?

**EDIT** - I also tested this with Java 18 and got the same result. I used a brand new file, a brand new folder, and I copied and pasted the text (not the file), into an empty file with the same name. Same error. I can't really get a cleaner test than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, file names are case-insensitive.  This means that files called Something$ABC.class and Something$Abc.class cannot be distinguished.

Meanwhile, of course, the language itself is case-sensitive, and expects the file name and the name of the class within the file to match.

Your only recourse seems to be to rename either the class or the interface.

Comment: Great catch, ty again. Question though - would this not be considered a bug that I should submit to Oracle? I feel like this should be addressed, because it very much sounds like it is attempting to create both a `ABC` and `Abc` class file. More importantly, this hurts portability, and the solution is really simple (just increment that `$1` to be `$2`)

Comment: You could try reporting it - I'm not sure how responsive they are.

Comment: (@davidalayachew) You _could_ compile in WSL, or more generally any Unix VM, or on a (different) real Unix machine, put in a jar and run from the jar on Windows; _jar_ entries are case-sensitive even when the 'real' (OS) filesystem is not. Less convenient though.

Comment: Fun fact: NTFS actually can be operated case-sensitive.  But you **really** don't want to do that.

Comment: @danglingelse I will do exactly that then, ty! I will post updates to the bug here.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you, I will use that as a workaround until they patch it

Comment: Ok, the bug has been submitted! Here is the link -- https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8287885

Comment: Well unfortunately, it seems that the developer doesn't agree, and thinks that this is only an enhancement. I have tried to appeal the decision, but it seems like they are not budging. Hopefully they change their mind.

Comment: As a follow up update, I started a discussion on this on the java mailing list here. A good faith effort was made by the compiler-dev folks, but it looks like this is an extremely complex situation to navigate out of. It wasn't shut down, but it doesn't look like any progress has been made for a few weeks now. Likely won't for a while either.

Comment: Here is the discussion -- https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/compiler-dev/2023-February/022222.html

Comment: I forgot to give an update - Wonderful news! Archie Cobbs was able to create an opt-in warning that catches and deals with this issue. Here is a demo of me using it on the preview version of JDK 21 -- https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/compiler-dev/2023-April/022930.html -- Thank you all for your help in improving Java!

Comment: I should also add - I built the JDK myself when doing this, but all of the prebuilt beta binaries should have this ready to go. As I said, I was late in giving this update. There have been several beta builds since.

Comment: I forgot to update, so here it is -- a new warning was created by Archie Cobbs and was released in Java 21. If you have Java 21 or later, either turn on all warnings, or turn on the `this-escape` warning. Once you have done so, the problem I described in post will throw a warning.

Comment: Here is how to turn on all warnings -- `javac -Xlint:all Abc.java`

Answer (score 0):

I just compiled the code and ran it on my machine. It works without any problems.

Maybe try to delete all existing class files and recompile everything.

Otherwise you can try a different java version, I had similar problems related to that in the past.

Comment: I have made a brand new folder, copied the text (not the file) into a brand new file. Compiled, ran it, same error. I should add, I also tested this in Java 18, and got the same error.

Comment: You're using Windows.  With case-insensitive file names.  I suspect that is somehow the cause.

Comment: @danglingelse oh wow, great catch. I tried to create a file in windows with same name but change in case, and it won't let me. I think that is my problem.

Comment: What command are you using to run the compiled files?

Comment: @danglingelse If you turn this into an answer, I will accept your solution

Comment: ok. will write it up.

Comment: @TwoOfTwelve I believe danglingelse has solved my solution, but I added my compile and run commands in my post.